# Delete requests returns true, but request still exists?

Tags: facebook, graph, apprequests

Possible answer or bug:  Using the user access token seems to work, it deletes the request and will throw an error when trying to read it in the future, but it still exists in the graph and providing apptoken still shows it, and for some reason wouldn't delete it.  Seems contrary to documentation, but changing apptoken to access token seemed to at least provide a workaround for me.

First, the code I'm using (as the one in the documentation always returned an entity not visible by user type message)

```
function do_delete_request($url, $optional_headers = null) 
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//include array of additional headers
if (count($optional_headers)) {
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $optional_headers);
}
return curl_exec($ch);
}
$full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id);  
$delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" .$full_request_id. "?access_token=".$apptoken;
$result = do_delete_request($delete_url);
```

I'm sorry if that's messy, I don't know how to format stuff here.  I'm at a loss after a lot of googling, I never ask this stuff.

$result returns true, over and over again.  Graph explorer shows the request still exists.

By deleting it, does that just mean I remove it from the requests interface for a user?  Or am I doing something wrong in my delete process?

I need a way to tell whether or not a request has been accepted already or not.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook sends the user to your app with the Request ID(s) in the URL, that's how you tell when a request has been accepted. It's up to you to check for a process a response to a request.

```
https://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]
```

As far as delete not working, is the request still their after some time? Facebook, and many busy sites, do heavy caching so things like delete may not be processed immediately.

Comment: Graph explorer shows it still exists, but only when sent with app access token, as amended at the beginning of the question.  I neglected to include the part of my code that got the request IDs, but yes it's there.

Comment: Interesting, I never really checked after I do a delete. If it's still there, but only for the app access token, that seems like it remains for reporting/stats purposes. Facebook would need to keep so they know your apps send/response rate for requests.